# Select file and display path

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show the path of a file I select from a dialog box, in a text box.

```
Sub SelectMonthlyFile()

    Dim Data As Office.FileDialog

    Set Data = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With Data
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select the file."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

        If .Show = True Then
            Path = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If

    End With

 End Sub
```

I show an error at `Path = .SelectedItems(1)`.

> variable is not defined

I named my cell Path and assumed that this would get the file path copied and pasted here.

Comment: At one point you say you're working with a text box, and then you say a range. Can you clarify which one it is?

Comment: The variable `Path` is not declared, just as the error message says...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you rename `Data` to something more meaningful. I've changed it to just `FileDialog`. The reason for your error is that the code has no idea what `Path` is. Note that I omitted the clearing of the filter, it is not needed.

```
Option Explicit 'always have this

Dim strPath As String 'explicitly declare your variable

 Sub SelectMonthlyFile()

   Dim FileDialog As Office.FileDialog

   Set FileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With FileDialog
     .AllowMultiSelect = False
     .Title = "Please select the file."
     .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
     .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

    'was anything selected?
     If .Show <> 0 Then
        strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Debug.Print strPath
     End If

    End With

 End Sub
```